# Mp3 Player using python 2.7 and pyglet on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, python-2.7, audio, pyglet

I am trying to make an mp3 player in python using pyglet and I want to display the current song name that is playing. I tried to use SourceInfo class, but I don't know how it works
 `pyglet.media.SourceInfo.title` doesn't show anything. Could you please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First all all, **make sure you got AvBin installed**!
Otherwise you won't be able to play much other than `wav` files.

Remember that this is just a rough mock up of what you need.
Build on it, scrap it.. But this is a start.

```
import pyglet
pyglet.options['audio'] = ('pulse', 'alsa')

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=800, height=600)

player=pyglet.media.Player()
# == Queue more tracks,
#    the label will update automatically
player.queue( pyglet.media.load('./Downloads/music/Pendulum - Hold Your Color.mp3', streaming=True) )
player.volume=0.3

# window is the variable 'window' from earlier.
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

    if player.playing:
        label = pyglet.text.Label('{artist} - {song}'.format(**{'artist' : player.source.info.author.decode('UTF-8'),
                                                                'song' : player.source.info.title.decode('UTF-8')}),
                              font_size=36,
                              x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2, # same here, window on line 6
                              anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
    else:
        label = pyglet.text.Label('Music paused!', font_size=36, x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
    label.draw()

    window.flip() # This is overkill but ensures proper rendering at all times.

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    # Up and Down controls the volume for instance
    if symbol == pyglet.window.key.UP:
        player.volume = player.volume+0.1
    elif symbol == pyglet.window.key.DOWN:
        player.volume = player.volume-0.1

    # Any key really will start/pause the playback
    elif player.playing:
        player.pause()
    else:
        player.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```